# Calculating the average angular speed given $ω_i$, $ω_f$, and $Δt$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

How did we calculate the average angular speed as outlined in the solution for question b? I understand how to solve this question by calculating the area below the curve on a ω-Δt graph, but I don't know how to get the average angular speed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @SolubleFish That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I changed it, thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the acceleration is constant, the velocity decreases linearly. Then, the average velocity is the velocity at the midpoint between the beginning and the end, that is, half the initial velocity